# PromiseKit: delegate-system wrappers seem to return immediately when not used at the beginning of the chain

Tags: swift, promisekit

I am fairly new to `PromiseKit` and I have been trying for a couple of days to figure out a solution for an unexpected behaviour of promise-wrapped delegate systems (UIALertView+PromiseKit, `PMKLocationManager` etc..).

In my fairly typical scenario of an app's Setup process, I am trying to chain up a series of operations that the user has to go through when the app loads.
For the sake of this example, let's restrict the case to only two steps:
logging the user into a Restful system followed by presenting an alertView and waiting for user's interaction.

Below is my code, where:

1. LoginToService is a promise-able version of a block-based method obtained via extending MCUser with `PromiseKit`. This works as expected and returns once the user had logged in, or fails with an error.
2. In the 'then' clause of the successful login, I present an alertView by returning its promised version via alert.promise().

   I would expect that promise to be fulfilled before the successive .then clause (and in the end the 'finally' clause) gets called - the alert's promise should be fulfilled when the the user clicks on button to dismiss it, as per implementation of PromiseKit's delegate system wrappers: this works just fine the observed behaviour when I use alert.promise().then to start the chain of Promises -

   ```
       // Doesn't work: alert.promise returns immediately 
   let user = MCUser.sharedInstance()
   user.logInToService(.RestServiceOne, delegate: self).then { _ -> AnyPromise in
       MCLogInfo("LogInToService: Promise fulfilled")
       let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Title", message: "Msg", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", otherButtonTitles: "Hello")
       return alert.promise()
       }.then { (obj:AnyObject) -> Void in
           print("Clicked")
       }.finally {
           print("Finally")
       }.catch_ { error in
    print("Error")
   }
   ```

What I observe is that the chain continues immediately without waiting for the user to click, with the 'Clicked' and 'Finally' messages being printed to console and the alert on screen waiting for an action. Am I obviously missing something or ar those delegate-system wrappers not meant to be used if not at the beginning of the Promise chain?

Thanks in advance for any hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work as you expect. You may check whether the returned promise is incorrectly completed.

What makes me gripes, though, is that `alert.promise()` should return a `Promise<Int>` - but the closure is explicitly typed to return a `AnyPromise`. So, your code should not compile.

I setup a test project myself, and indeed, the compiler complains. I used PromiseKit v3.x. Your's is likely an older version (`finally` and `catch` are deprecated).

After fixing the return type of the closure to `Promise<Int>`, the code compiles. But the important fact is, that the behaviour is as you described and experienced in your code - and not as it should, IMHO. So, there seems to be a bug.

**Edit:**

OK, it turned out that there is an issue with "overload resolution" and "type inference". Given your code in your OP, the Swift compiler resolves to an unexpected overload of the `then` method:

expected:
`func then<U>(on q: dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_get_main_queue(), _ body: (T) throws -> Promise<U>) -> Promise<U>`

actual:
`func then<U>(on q: dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_get_main_queue(), _ body: (T) throws -> U) -> Promise<U>`

This is caused by the *succeeding* `finally` and `catch` methods.

In order to solve it here in this scenario, you should either *correctly* fully specify the type of the closure, or let the compiler figure it out themselves by not specifying the type. I finally got this, which works as expected using PromiseKit v3.x with Swift:

```
import UIKit
import PromiseKit

// helper
func fooAsync() -> Promise<String> {
    return Promise { fulfill, reject in
        let delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(1.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0)) {
            fulfill("OK")
        }
    }
}        


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()            
        fooAsync()
        .then { str in
            print("String: \(str)")
            let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Title", message: "Msg", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", otherButtonTitles: "Hello")
            let promise: Promise<Int> = alert.promise()
            return promise
        }.then { (n: Int) -> Void in   // notice: closure type specified!
            print("Clicked")
        }.ensure {
            print("Finally")
        }.report { error in
            print("Error")
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

This above code may not solve it in your case, since you are using a different PromiseKit library. I would recommend to use the newest Swift version.

Nonetheless, there seem to be some subtle pitfalls here with PromiseKit. Hope you can now solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, happy to hear that's not the intended behaviour. I am using the UIAlertView's example here as that's all PromiseKit code so the completion of its promise should not be dependant on an eventual bug of mine. I  this case, alert.promise() returns both as soon as the promise() method implementation ends, thus continuing the chain to the end, as well we when the user clicks on the button at a later stage.

Comment: @MattewUK I made some additional comments, please check.

Comment: one detail I did omit above is that I am using the Obj-C version of it (UIAlertView+PromiseKit), where promise() returns AnyPromise, therefore it compiles and runs. I was also setting up a test project using the Swift version of it but as you pointed out I get the same odd behaviour. Thanks for taking the time to double check, I may have to go forward and raise an issue.

Comment: @MattewUK Finally, I found the issue and got a working version. Please see my updated post.

Comment: great job there, I can't thank you enough for spotting this. In fact, it looks like that using a fully specified return type by switching to the Swift implementation works fine even in the library version I am using. I'll edit the bug report and let the guys dig into the issue as it seems it may effect other scenarios. If you feel like sharing more of the resolution process and how you ended up finding the overload resolution / type inference issue...well, it'd be an extremely interesting read. Appreciated.